# Setting the place Python Looks for Files in CMD

Tags: python, command-line

I'm trying to run a python program off the internet that uses files linked relative to it's location. When I try to run it, cmd says:

```
C:\Users\John's Account>Python
C:\PythonWorkingDirectory\udemy-dl-master\setup.py Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\PythonWorkingDirectory\udemy-dl-master\setup.py", line 10, in <module>
     requirements = [pkg.split('=')[0] for pkg in open('requirements.txt').readlines()]
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest creating a requirements.txt file in that directory or pointing your request at the proper location of your requirements.txt file.

Comment: Used indentation to improve layout of the error message

Comment: print os.getcwd() to determine the current directory of the script